# How to escape curly braces in my properties file which is fetched using the ResourceBundle API

Tags: java, resourcebundle

In properties file I am having a `key=A: {{0}, {1}}, B: {{2}, {3}}`. I am expecting a string `"A: {0, 1}, B: {1, 2}"`. The numbers inside the curly braces are parsing. How can I include the character '{' without binding to any value? I also tried by escaping the character like this "//{". Even I couldn't get the expected result. An error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number 0, 1 \ occurs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
key=A: '{'{0}, {1}'}', B: '{'{2}, {3}'}'
```

Answer (score 2):

just run the properties file through native2ascii tool that comes with the JDK. it will do the work for you. Or better use the [JRCEditor](http://www.zaval.org/products/jrc-editor/)