# Single Curly Bracket in Properties file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, properties

I am trying to read this text which has only a single curly brace

```
Y8R30j)i{sjmPXfE
```

from a .properties file using `MessageResources.getMessage()`

and am getting this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmatched braces in the pattern.
at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:508)
at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:363)
```

I tried to escape by using

```
Y8R30j)i'{'sjmPXfE
```

but am getting the same exception.

Comment: **How** are you reading that property?

Comment: tried to escape this ?

Comment: Yes I tried 
Y8R30j)i'{'sjmPXfE

But i get the same exception

Comment: Did you try `\{` and `'''{'`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779734/how-to-escape-curly-braces-in-my-properties-file-which-is-fetched-using-the-reso possible duplicate

Comment: @DaveNewton  I have tried both and still same Exception

Comment: @SusheelSingh Please see question and exception to see difference with your link.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch in the properties file i have a key com.abc.xyz=Y8R30j)i'{'sjmPXfE and am using MessageResources.getMessage("com.abc.xyz",null); to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

org.apache.struts.util.MessageResources uses java.text.MessageFormat which interprets things between curly braces as patterns or placeholders to be replaced with strings.

Per the exception it is clear that java is not able to find the closing brace for the opening curly brace you have in your key value, possible workaround (working with struts 1.3) is below. ( in light of unicode escaping or any other escaping not working, can refer to java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern() method for further escaping possibles)

Specify key as below in message resources file -

```
key=Y8R30j)i{0}sjmPXfE
```

Read value of the key with the code below in your action (or any other java) class

```
MessageResources messages = MessageResources.getMessageResources("MessageResources");
Object[] leftCurlyBrace = { "{" };
String value = messages.getMessage(request.getLocale(), "key", leftCurlyBrace);
```

Am assuming you are trying to read some encrypted value from a properties file in a struts 1.x J2EE environment